# mySQL showing rows that have multiple occurences of common attributes

Tags: mysql, join, attributes, subquery, exists

I'm having some trouble displaying the data in a particular way.

**I want to display the mechanics that 3 or more skills in common.**

I'm not sure how to get a count on common skills, I tried using EXIST and subqueries but couldn't figure it out.

Here is the query I have to display all the Mechanics with thier skills

```
Select distinct fName, lName , Skill  from Person 
inner join Worker on Person.personID = Worker.personID
inner join Mechanic on Worker.personID = Mechanic.personID
inner join Skills on Mechanic.personID = Skills.personID
order by fName
```

Which shows

```
fName   lName   Skill
----------------------------
Carl    Marx    fuel systems
Jimmy   John    heating and cooling systems
Jimmy   John    exhaust systems
Jimmy   John    fluid and filter service
Mike    Hawk    resurface rotors and drums
Mike    Hawk    struts and suspension
Mike    Hawk    engine performance (tune-up)
Mike    Hawk    wheel alignment
Ricky   Bobby   wheel alignment
Ricky   Bobby   resurface rotors and drums
Ricky   Bobby   A/C systems
Ricky   Bobby   struts and suspension
Ricky   Bobby   heating and cooling systems
Terry   Cruz    sound systems
Terry   Cruz    cruise control
```

The output should be

```
Ricky   Bobby
Mike    Hawk
```

Here is the relation scheme
[image: RelationScheme]

Thanks in advance! Let me know if I can provide anything else

Comment: We need more information regarding display.  Because if `{A,B}`  have 3 skill in common and `{A, C }` different skill but also 3 what will be your display?

Comment: Hmm im not sure I understand what you are asking, I just want to show which Mechanics have Skills in common. If A and C have 3 skills but only 1 in common, nothing will show. A and C must have 3 skills in common.

If A and B have 3 skills in common, A and C have 3 skills in common, but B and C have no skills in common,  It should show A, B and C because they have 3 in common with at least one other person

Comment: Based on your example, Jimmy John and Ricky bobby does not have any common skill; and based on your requirement, you need a query that would output the mechanics which has the same skill, am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, you are right they dont have a common skill, the output should be Ricky Bobby and Mike Hawk

Comment: You have made it co,plicated u can use simple >=  to show the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/WEZR94368)**

```
SELECT `fNameA`, `lNameA`, `fNameB`, `lNameB`, GROUP_CONCAT(`SkillA`, ' ') as Skills
FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT 
                CASE WHEN M1.`id` < M2.`id` THEN M1.`fName` ELSE M2.`fName` END as `fNameA`,
                CASE WHEN M1.`id` < M2.`id` THEN M1.`lName` ELSE M2.`lName` END as `lNameA`,
                CASE WHEN M1.`id` < M2.`id` THEN M2.`fName` ELSE M1.`fName` END as `fNameB`,
                CASE WHEN M1.`id` < M2.`id` THEN M2.`fName` ELSE M1.`fName` END as `lNameB`,
                M1.`Skill` as `SkillA`, M2.`Skill` as `SkillB`
        FROM Mechanic M1
        JOIN Mechanic M2
          ON M1.`id` <> M2.`id`
         AND M1.`Skill` = M2.`Skill`  
        ORDER BY M1.`id`, M2.`id`) T
GROUP BY `fNameA`, `lNameA`, `fNameB`, `lNameB`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

**SIMPLE VERSION** Just print first two fields

```
SELECT  M1.`fName`, M1.`lName`, M2.`fName`, M2.`lName`
FROM Mechanic M1
JOIN Mechanic M2
  ON M1.`id` <> M2.`id`
 AND M1.`Skill` = M2.`Skill` 
GROUP BY M1.`fName`, M1.`lName`, M2.`fName`, M2.`lName`
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

**OUTPUT**

- partial result
- first version with skill list
- simple version
  [image]

Comment: Wow thanks  alot, Can you explain to me what the M1 and M2 is? Im getting unknown M1.'id' in 'field list'

Comment: Check the `DEMO`. I use your result, you need to replace with `join` from your tables. In your case should be `MechanicID` or `PersonID` not sure which one. just something to identify each person.

Comment: Okay I replaced id with personID but my mechanic table doesnt have fName it only has skills as the attribute. I think my situation is a little different because  I have fName and lName in the person table which is joined to worker then to mechanic. Ill try to link them, What do you call using M1 and M2 on the mechanic table? id like to learn more about it

Comment: by the way the last query is perfect and is what the output should be

Comment: is call `alias` you can change the name of tables or fields

Comment: I realize you probably need add `DISTINCT` in case `MIKE` has also 3 skills in common with someone else will show twice.

Answer (score 0):

select fname,lname from Person where skills >= 3 order by fname

Comment: Its not who has 3 or more skills, its who has 3 or more skills in common

I have the query for showing who has 3 or more skills


`Select fName, lName, count(Person.personID) as 'Skill Amt' from   Person
inner join Worker on Person.personID = Worker.personID
inner join Mechanic on Worker.personID = Mechanic.personID
inner join Skills on Mechanic.personID = Skills.personID
group by Person.personID having count(Skills.skill) >= 3
order by Person.personID`